# Can't convert vim macro text to normal characters

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm trying to save a vim macro that I wrote into my `.vimrc` file.  I successfully recorded the macro into register `s`, the contents of which display as:

```
.,.s/S:/\&AHOMW€kbW€kbE/:.,.s/\\/\//g'€kb0
```

I next put an instruction in my `.vimrc` file as follows:

```
let @s=':.,.s/S:/\&AHOMW€kbW€kbE/:.,.s/\\/\//g'€kb0'
```

When I start a new vim session, as vim is starting up it complains about the "let" command being an invalid expression. In my searching I've come across something call a "normal" command that appears to be able to convert an expression like the one above into normal text.  I've tried the "normal" command and an "exe ""normal ... "" " command, but neither gives me back a translated version of my macro text in plain characters.

What is the proper approach to being able to define a "let" instruction with plain text macro instructions derived from the above type of example which is how the macro first gets saved in the s register during an active editing session?

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your macro contains a single quote, and you're trying to quote the entire string with single quotes without escaping the single quote in the macro.  Vim has a slightly unusual way of escaping a single quote inside single quote strings, and that is to just add another single quote. For example:

```
let @s=':.,.s/S:/\&AHOMW€kbW€kbE/:.,.s/\\/\//g''€kb0'
```

Comment: That solved the problem.  I never noticed that extra quote in there.  Thank you much, it is working great now.